# Is it possible to permanently change the Powershell working directory from a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I wanted to write this simple script as a proof of concept, but it's not behaving like I expected...

```
mkdir %1
cd %1
touch main.py
vim main.py
```

The new directory and file are created, and the file is opened in Vim properly, which means that the call to `cd` was successful, but the Powershell instance reverts back to the old directory when the script finishes execution. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You could force the command processor to `cd` to that directory whenever it starts using `regedit`

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: See this: http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/using-autorun-execute-commands-when-command-prompt-starts.html This link will explain better then me

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to input a command through Powershell that both creates a new directory and navigates to that directory. I don't think AutoRun can be used that way.

Comment: I don't understand: you run a batch file from PS prompt? that's not so common.

Comment: My fault. I didnt read the title properly.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a batch file, just any sort of script file that can make changes to the working directory of the Powershell console. Batch just seemed like the most appropriate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148003/discussion-between-stevefest-and-jace).

Comment: @Jace, I may not understand your problem, but why not write a short `mdcd.ps1` script that takes the directory you want to create a change to using `param` and then simply `mkdir` and then `cd` into it?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've tried this approach, but the `cd` command executes in a separate instance of Powershell from the one I'm working in.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Never mind, your suggestion works. For some reason, it works in a .ps1 file but not a .bat.

Answer (score 1):

I browsed through Stack Overflow and I found this.

---

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -command "& {Set-Location $env:systemroot}" 
powershell.exe -NoExit -command "& {Set-Location "D:\path\path}"
```

Set this command to a `Powershell` shortcut, issue fixed(of course change `$env` to what you need)

Also, you could start your own script in the `-command` flag.

Comment: A Powershell shortcut might be the way to go. Is it possible to define a shortcut as `$shortcut = new.bat arg1 & cd arg1 & touch main.py & vim main.py` and then invoke as `$shortcut arg1`?

Comment: I don't know Powershell very well, so I couldn't answer it. But you could `write-host` your file to somewhere else, and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it working. The solution was to run the script from a .ps1 file instead of .bat. Not sure why the .ps1 behaves differently, but I'll take it.

```
Param([string]$filepath)
mkdir $filepath
cd $filepath
touch main.py
vim main.py
```